# Use for loop inside another for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a file in rainbow colors. But however I have a problem, here is my code:

```
color = [91, 93, 92, 96, 94, 95]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
for i in f.read():
    for c in color:
        print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
              .format(c, i), end='', flush=True)
```

The question is, I want the output like this: `Hello`(`H` in red, `e` in yellow, etc. ), but I got the output like this:`HHHHHeeeeellll...`(first `H` in red, second `H` in yello, etc.).

I know that because the first `for` will loop the second `for`. But how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to loop over the colours for each letter just cycle through the colours, you can use `itertools.cycle` to cycle through the colors just calling `next()` to get the next color:

```
from itertools import cycle
color = cycle([91, 93, 92, 96, 94, 95])

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for i in f.read():
       print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
             .format(next(color), i), end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: It turns [1,2,3] into the infinite list [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...] but without the overhead of creating the list (see generators)

Comment: I understand, it will create a generator, and that turns [1,2,3] into `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...] `. Then we use `next()` to call it. right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate them in a "zipping" way, possibly repeating the second one.

```
color = [91, 93, 92, 96, 94, 95]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for i, c in itertools.izip(f.read(), itertools.cycle(color)):
        print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
          .format(c, i), end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: hum, I got this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'`

Comment: In python 3 you don't need `itertools.izip` just `zip` will do.

Comment: It's working! and what's the difference between your answer and @achampion 's answer?

Comment: Not much, both use `cycle` to create an infinite list of cycling colors, but this uses `zip()` to join the letter and color, vs. just calling `next()` on the cycle generator directly. `zip()` does the `next()` call for you but has a little more overhead because it creates a tuple which you unpack in the for loop.

Comment: @achampion so use `zip` and `cycle` will create a tuple and a  generator. but only use `cycle` will just create generator?

Comment: `zip()` is also a generator, a generator of tuples that calls `next()` on the 2 iterators you pass it, in this case the output is `[(next(letter), next(color)), (next(letter), next(color)), ...]` and will stop when it runs out of letters or colors, `itertools.cycle(colors)` ensures it never runs out of colors. `for i, c in zip(...)` unpacks the tuple `i, c = letter, color`

Comment: Just to be clear the overhead is minor and I would have no issue using either of these solutions, `zip()` is idiomatic when trying to deal with 2 lists at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you shouldn't use a second for loop.

You can use a `color_index` (initial value: 0), and you increment it (**modulo the number of colors**) at every loop, and use it: `color[color_index]`.