# `re` module: how to remove all HTML tags?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that can download a question from Stack Overflow using Python 3. And now I finished, here's the code:

```
import os
import re
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535816/use-for-loop-inside-another-for-in-python-3')

req.add_header("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)\
               AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
               Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36")

html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
webpage = html.read().decode('utf-8')

text = re.search(r'<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">.+?</div>',
                  webpage, re.S)

with open('text', 'w') as f:
    for i in text.group():
        f.write(i)
```

The output is:

```
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">

<p>I'm trying to print a file in rainbow colors. But however I have a problem, here is my code:</p>

<pre><code>color = [91, 93, 92, 96, 94, 95]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
for i in f.read():
    for c in color:
        print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
              .format(c, i), end='', flush=True)
</code></pre>

<p>the question is, I want the output like this: <code>Hello</code>(<code>H</code> in red, <code>e</code> in yellow, etc. )</p>

<p>but I got the output like this:<code>HHHHHeeeeellll...</code>(first <code>H</code> in red, second <code>H</code> in yello, etc.)</p>

<p>I know that because the first <code>for</code> will loop the second <code>for</code>. So how can I solve this?</p>
    </div>
```

I think it's working so good, but I want remove all HTML tags. And I've tried use `re.sub` like this:

```
text = re.sub('<.+?>', '', text)
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 18, in <module>
    text = re.sub('<.+?>', '', text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 179, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What does this mean and how can I solve this?

Comment: `text` is a match object.

Comment: @vaultah So `re` can't do that?

Comment: It basicly can, but only for sufficiently simple HTML input, regex works only on a *lexical level*. HTML can contain recursion which cannot be - semantically - handled by regular expressions.

Comment: @Wolf Thanks, let me learn about ``BeautifulSoup`` or ``lxml``. Which is recommend?

Comment: [BeautifulSoup and lxml.html - what to prefer? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4967103/2301450) ...